# Работа с randomize

Tags: pascal

> Даны две действительные квадратные матрицы порядка 10 и 20.  В строках с отрицательным элементом на главной диагонали найти произведение всех элементов.

Если организовывать ввод матрицы вручную, все работает. С randomize работает не всегда, часто выдает ошибку eitcode=21. Как это исправить?

```
Const n =   20;

Type matr =   array [1..n, 1..n] Of integer;
    vek =   array[1..n] Of LongInt;

Var 
    A,B:   matr;
    VA,VB:   vek;
Procedure wwod(Var A: matr; k,p: byte);

Var i,j:   byte;
Begin
    Writeln('Ввод матрицы ',k,'-го порядка');
    randomize;
    For i:= 1 To k Do
        Begin
            For j:= 1 To p Do
                Begin
                    A[i,j] := random(10)-4;
                    Write(A[i,j]:2,' ');
                End;
            readln;
        End;
End;
Procedure proizv(Var A: matr; k,p: byte; Var VA: vek);

Var i,j:   byte;
    v,f:   integer;
Begin
    For i:= 1 To k Do
        Begin
            f := j;
            For j:=1  To p Do
                If i=j Then If A[i,j]<0 
                Then
                    Begin
                        Begin
                            v := 1;
                            For f:=1 To p Do
                                v := v*A[i,f]
                        End;
                        Writeln('Произведение элементов ', i, ' строки - ',v);
                    End
                Else
                    Begin
                        Writeln('На главной диагонали находится положительный элемент');
                        break;
                    End;
        End;
    Readln;
End;
Begin
    wwod(A, 10, 10);
    proizv(A,10,10,VA);
    wwod(B, 20, 20);
    proizv(B,20,20,VB);
End.
```

Comment: отформатируйте код и уберите пустые строки

Comment: У меня ошибок не возникает. ReadLn из первой процедуры я заменил на WriteLn, а из второй процедуры удалил ReadLn и написал его перед последним End. Использовал компиляторы Turbo Pascal и Pascal ABC.NET - работает прекрасно и там, и там. Если ошибка есть, то на каком этапе возникает?

Comment: free pascal и короче я понял в чем ошибка он перемножает не строку как задано в цикле а от этого элемента до конца матрицы. Проверь пожалуйста правильно ли перемножает строку и если работает вопрос: где скачать turbopascal для win7 64bit?

Comment: Turbo Pascal уже старый, его скорее всего нет для Win7 64.

Comment: все равно и в Turbo Pascal пишет нереальное произведение. В чем ошибка?

Comment: ага все отладил, но как сделать чтоб random генерировал меньше нулей, если увеличить границы у матрицы 20 порядка возникает переполнение(значение больше максимально допустимого этим типом)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readln` в процедуре `wwod` не нужен

`randomize` лучше вынести в тело программы

---

`Randomize` лучше не вызывать перед каждым использованием `random`, так как при этом генератор псевдослучайных чисел "сбрасывает" свое состояние, используя текущее время как *seed*. Если это происходит за короткий промежуток времени, и системные время не успевает сильно измениться, то random будет выдавать похожие последовательности.

Comment: так визуально хуже и все равно ошибка.

Comment: @rentscan обновил ответ